# "Select All" action button doesn't work

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I created two action buttons `Select All` and `Deselect All`. For some reason, `Deselect All` works but `Select All` **doesn't**.

Why is that? The `Deselect All` button unhighlights all rows as I expect. However, `Select All` button doesn't do anything.

`input$selectAll` and `input$deselectAll` are updated correctly (as shown in the `TEMP` tab)

Can anybody help? Here is my code. Thanks!

DATASET:

```
colA <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
colB <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
rawdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(colA,colB))
View(rawdata)
```

server.R

```
function(input, output, session) {

  # Update summaryTable When users click 'Select All'
  summaryTable <- eventReactive (input$selectAll,{
      print("SelectAll")
      DT::datatable(rawdata, selection = list(target = 'row', selected = c(1:ncol(rawdata()))))
  })

  # Update summaryTable When users click 'Deselect All'
  summaryTable <- eventReactive (input$deselectAll,{
      print("deselectAll")
      DT::datatable(rawdata, selection = list(target = 'row', selected = c(0)))
  })


  # Default SummaryTable
  output$inputVars <- DT::renderDataTable({

      if (input$selectAll==0 & input$deselectAll==0) {
          print("Default")
          DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
      } else {
          summaryTable()
      }
  })

  output$temp <- renderPrint({
    print(input$selectAll)
    print(input$deselectAll)
  })

}
```

ui.R

```
fluidPage(

  mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(id = "allResults",
        tabPanel(value='inputVars',title='Variable Selection', 
                  verticalLayout(
                      DT::dataTableOutput('inputVars'),
                      br(),
                      fluidRow(align="bottom", 
                             column(2, actionButton("selectAll"  , strong("Select All"))),
                             column(3, actionButton("deselectAll", strong("Deselect All")))
                      )

                  )
                ),
        tabPanel(value='temp',title="TEMP", verbatimTextOutput("temp"))
      )
  )

)
```

Comment: U want to select the columns or rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? Note that I changed `ncol` to `nrow` as SelecteAll is appropriate with the rows

```
library(shiny)
colA <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
colB <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
rawdata <- as.data.frame(cbind(colA,colB))

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id = "allResults",
                tabPanel(value='inputVars',title='Variable Selection', 
                         verticalLayout(
                           DT::dataTableOutput('inputVars'),
                           br(),
                           fluidRow(align="bottom", 
                                    column(2, actionButton("selectAll"  , strong("Select All"))),
                                    column(3, actionButton("deselectAll", strong("Deselect All")))
                           )
                         )
                ),
                tabPanel(value='temp',title="TEMP", verbatimTextOutput("temp"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  var <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$selectAll,{
    print("SelectAll")
    var$selected <- 1:nrow(rawdata)
  })

  observeEvent(input$deselectAll,{
    print("deselectAll")
    var$selected <- 0
  })

  # Default SummaryTable
  output$inputVars <- DT::renderDataTable({
    if (input$selectAll==0 & input$deselectAll==0) {
      print("Default")
      DT::datatable(rawdata, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
    } 
    else {
      DT::datatable(rawdata, selection = list(target = 'row', selected = var$selected))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]